# Is there a jakarta equivalent to javax.sql.DataSource and javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa

We just upgraded to Spring 3.0.1, and replaced javax.peristence-api with jakarta.persistence-api.

REMOVED:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

ADDED:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jakarta.persistence.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Question is this:  Is there a jakarta replacement for these?

javax.sql.DataSource

javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Not finding that the jakarta.persistence-api has a replacement for them

The error comes from this class.  Might be legacy and an old way of managing JPA, transactions, datasource, etc... Might we be able to get rid of it, or update it?  Hoping to find some helpful suggestions

```
package com.orders.persistence.jpa;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.orders.persistence.jpa.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Value( "${driverClassName}" )
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value( "${url}" )
    private String url;

    @Value("${username}")
    private String jdbcUsername;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String jdbcPassword;

    @Value( "${hibernateDialect}" )
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value( "${hibernateShowSql}" )
    boolean hibernateShowSql;

    @Value( "${hibernateHbm2ddlAuto}" )
    private String hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;

    @Value( "${jpaGenerateDdl}" )
    boolean jpaGenerateDdl;

    @Value("${useQueryCache}")
    boolean useQueryCache;

    public PersistenceJPAConfig(){
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
      return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager(){
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource( dataSource() );
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                "com.orders.persistence.jpa",
                "com.orders.persistence.model",
                "com.orders.persistence.service",
                });

        final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(){
            {
                setDatabase( Database.MYSQL );
                setDatabasePlatform( hibernateDialect );
                setShowSql( hibernateShowSql );
                setGenerateDdl( jpaGenerateDdl );
            }
        };
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter( vendorAdapter );
        entityManager.setJpaProperties( additionalProperties() );
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName( driverClassName );
        dataSource.setUrl( url );
        dataSource.setUsername( jdbcUsername );
        dataSource.setPassword( jdbcPassword );
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( entityManager().getObject() );
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties(){
        return new Properties(){
            {// use this to inject additional properties in the EntityManager
                setProperty("useSecondLevelCache", "org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory");
                setProperty("useQueryCache", "org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer on this question? I have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @JanD.M. Unfortunately No.  Am still using javax.sql.DataSource;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was stuck with this to, but some javax import are unchanged like javax.sql.dataSource.

> These are not affected by the Jakarta EE namespace migration, but stay
> as they are. Some examples are:
>
> javax.sql.* javax.transaction.xa.* javax.xml.* javax.naming.*
> javax.swing.*

https://www.agilejava.eu/2021/01/22/migration-guide/

Comment: javax.imageio also remained untouched

Comment: Spent hours looking for solution to this problem. Thank You for providing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

just keep it, in my DB config file, it is:

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

Answer (score 1):

I found a doc about this:

Unaffected (Non-EE) Packages

https://github.com/jakartaee/platform/blob/main/namespace/unaffected-packages.adoc

`javax.sql` is one of these packages, so you can use is AS-IS